# PHP | MYSQL | Nested PDO::beginTransition() and PDO::commit() on different DBs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im facing up a doubt: what happen if i disable autocommit for 2 different connections to 2 different databases, in a nested way?

Example code:

```
 $conn = new MainDB(); // DB class
 $conn_second = new NotMainDB(); // another DB class

try {

    $conn->dbh->beginTransaction(); // disable autocommit
    $conn_second->dbh->beginTransaction(); // disable autocommit on 2nd DB

    $run = $conn->dbh->prepare(/* UPDATE STATEMENT */);
    $run->execute();

    $run = $conn->dbh->prepare(/* ANOTHER UPDATE STATEMENT */);
    $run->execute();

    $ssp = $conn_second->dbh->prepare(/* AN INSERT STATEMENT ON ANOTHER DB */);
    $ssp->execute();

    $conn_second->dbh->commit();
    $conn->dbh->commit();
} catch (Exception $ex) {

    $conn->dbh->rollBack();
    $conn_second->dbh->rollBack();
}
```

is there anything i have to take care of? anyone already experienced such a case?

thanks

Comment: I've used 2 databases exactly that way in the past with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work even if both of the connections refer to the same database.

Think of it this way: when you set up your Apache normally and two users visit your site at once, they open transactions simultaneously, and there are no problems whatsoever.

Basically, it's perfectly normal state for a database to handle multiple connections at once.

Just be sure not to cause any deadlocks though. Deadlocks happen when A waits for B to finish, and B waits for A to finish. I imagine this might happen for example when you use triggers with circular dependencies. These are rather rare scenarios though, especially for PHP, and deadlocks happen usually on user application level rather than on DB level.